# Bluetooth headphones not connecting with reason 0x16

Tags: network, audio, bluetooth, headphones

I am running a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015), 2.7 GHz Intel Core i5, 16 GB 1867 MHz DDR3, Intel Iris Graphics 6100 1536 MB with macOS version 10.12.2. I have had a problem with my headphones for a long time where every now and then it begins to refuse to connect. When I look at the problem in Bluetooth Explorer I see the following in the logs:

```
Sennheiser MM500-X connected, handle: 0xE
2017-03-23 14:54:59 +0000 Handle: 0xE disconnected, reason: 0x16
Sennheiser MM500-X disconnected
```

I also see the graph of the link quality for that device look like this: `[\_  ]`

I know that 0x16 is AKA "Terminated by local host" but I don't exactly know what that means. Does it mean the local computer is stopping the connection? Could, actually, it be some scenario sideways (like the host is disconnecting because the headphones aren't responsive)?

If you need any further information just let me know! I have uploaded a photo of the device information from when it last connected which might help.

[image: bluetooth device details]

Comment: Were you able to fix this problem? I have the same problem with the Sennheiser's PXC550 headphone. 