# Bluetooth headphones keep disconnecting from my MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, bluetooth, headphones

I have a pair of [OnePlus Buds Z](https://www.oneplus.com/product/oneplus-buds-z) and a Macbook Pro late 2015. I tried several methods explained [on this blog](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/394776/bluetooth-headphone-constantly-disconnecting), but every single solution (like reset the Bluetooth module or writing some instructions on the command) didn't work.

I can connect my headphones, but when I remove them from their case, they instantly disconnect. I also tried to pair [Samsung Galaxy Buds](https://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/audio/galaxy-buds/#compare), but I had the same problem.

Anyone know how to resolve this annoying problem?
Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Which blog are you referring to? Could you add the URL to your question?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/394776/bluetooth-headphone-constantly-disconnecting